# XSLT 1.0 template Muenchian grouping

Tags: templates, xslt-1.0, muenchian-grouping

I use a tool where a xslt template is pre-defined and it is not desirable to remove it.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<Msg xmlns="urn:com.sap.b1i.vplatform:entity">
  <xsl:copy-of select="/vpf:Msg/@*"></xsl:copy-of>
  <xsl:copy-of select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Header"></xsl:copy-of>
  <Body>
    <xsl:copy-of select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/*"></xsl:copy-of>
    <Payload Role="X" id="{$atom}">
      <xsl:call-template name="transform"></xsl:call-template>
    </Payload>
  </Body>
</Msg>
```

`<xsl:template name="transform">
<!-- In this area we write our xpath and build the xml-file-->
 </xsl:template>`

Now I want to use the Muenchian grouping method. But for this method you also need to define a template en key. Like this:

```
<xsl:key name="KeyOrder" match="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[@id='atom8']/Orders/jdbc:Row" use="jdbc:RecId2" />
<xsl:template match="Orders" >
<Documents>
  <xsl:for-each select="jdbc:Row[count(. | key('KeyOrder', jdbc:RecId2)[1]) = 1]">
    <xsl:sort select="jdbc:RecId2" />
    <Document>
      <xsl:copy-of select="jdbc:RecId2" />
      <xsl:for-each select="key('KeyOrder', jdbc:RecId2)">
        <xsl:sort select="jdbc:OrderNrRef" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Document>
  </xsl:for-each>
</Documents>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem is that the 2 templates won't work togetheter the way I copied it here. That means, I don't get the Muenchian grouping results. It's only works when I 'disable' xsl:template match="/", but then I lose a lot of other information which is necessary further in the process.

So how can I get in my XML file the results of both templates?

Comment: Not sure I understand completely, but couldn't you add an `<xsl:apply-templates select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[@id='atom8']/Orders"/>` to the template named `transform`?

Comment: hi Daniel , thank you.
I add the line to the 'transform' template and it works correct. I receive in the XML both results.


    <xsl:template name="transform">
          <xsl:apply-templates 
    select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[@id='atom8']/Orders"/>
          <test>
            <xsl:value-of 
  select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[@id='atom8']/Orders/jdbc:Row/jdbc:RecId2"/>
          </test>
        </xsl:template>